# Complex functions and residues

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that, since the complex function
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z(e^z-1)}$$
have a pole of 2nd order in z=0, I should be able to represent it as:
$$f(z)=\frac{g(z)}{(z-0)^2}$$
*Being g(z) a function that is both analytic and different from zero when z=0.*

But the only expression for g(z) that I was able to get to was
$$g(z)=\frac{z}{e^z-1}$$
wich doesn't meets the criteria explained before.

Can anyone say what am I getting wrong?
Does f(z) really have a pole of 2nd order in zero?

Comment: "wich doesn't meets the criteria explained before" Hmmm... why do you think it does not?

Comment: @Did well, because g(z) has a singularity when z=0, doensn´t it? That would make it a non-analytic function in this point from what I know, but I could be wrong of course

Comment: $g(z)$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$, since $\lim_{z\to 0} g(z) = 1$. You can make it analytic by defining $$ g(z) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{z}{e^z-1}, & z \ne 0 \\ 1, & z = 0 \end{cases} $$

Comment: How is the post below that you chose to accept, answering the question?

Comment: @Dylan yes, I realized that after a while, thank you!

Comment: @Did it helped me realize that I could use L'Hopital to calculate the value of g(0).

Comment: @RodrigoCastañon This comment is surprising... Using L'H to compute $\lim\limits_{z\to0}g(z)$ (rather than $g(0)$) is absurd since $1/g(z)$ is already a variation ratio hence $\lim\limits_{z\to0}1/g(z)$ is **already** a derivative **by definition**.

Comment: @Did I'm not sure if I understood.. isn't it always possible to use L'H when working with 0/0 idefinitions? If not, how am I suposed to compute the value of g(0) then?

Comment: Yes it is possible and in some cases it is absurd. The present case is one of these. If you know the limit of $(e^z-1)/z$ when $z\to0$ (and you need to know this limit if you want to use L'H) then you do not need to invoke L'H at all.

Comment: @Did Why would i need to know the limit of $(e^z-1)/z$ when $z\to0$ to use L'H? I just need to know the derivative of $f(z)=z$ and $g(z)=(e^z-1)$, right?

Comment: Because "to know the derivative of $g(z)=e^z-1$" at $z=0$ is exactly to know how to compute the limit of the ratio $(g(z)-g(0))/(z-0)=(e^z-1)/z$. And if you know this limit, why mention L'H at all?

Comment: @RodrigoCastañon I think what they're saying is, the limit $\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{e^z-1}{z}$, is by definition, the derivative of $$ \frac{d}{dz}e^z\Bigg\vert_{z=0} = \lim_{z\to 0}\frac{e^z-e^0}{z-0} $$

Comment: @Did To be fair, I didn't immediately connect it with the derivative definition either. I first found the limit through the power series of $e^z$. In the end, does it really matter as long as you get the right answer?

Comment: @Dylan Plese see previous comments.

Comment: @Dylan "I think OP got it now." You did, apparently, but I am not sure the OP did. Experience says that students raised in the religion of L'H often find difficult to see this trick and its domain of applicability in an objective light (and the present comment thread could be viewed as yet another exhibit of this odd phenomenon...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just taking my first complex analysis but from my understanding you are correct in the fact that pole z= 0 is of second order.

Using the formula for higher order poles.

$$Res_{z \rightarrow x} = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} lim_{z\rightarrow x} \frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}(z-x)^n f(z)$$

Where x is the pole 0 and n is the order.

Using this formula:

$$Res_{z \rightarrow 0} = \frac{1}{(2-1)!} lim_{z\rightarrow 0} \frac{d^{2-1}}{dz^{2-1}}(z-0)^2 f(z)$$

$$Res_{z \rightarrow 0} = \frac{1}{(1)!} lim_{z\rightarrow x} \frac{d}{dz}(z-0)^2 \frac{1}{z(e^z - 1)}$$

$$  lim_{z\rightarrow 0} \frac{d}{dz}(z)^2 \frac{1}{z(e^z - 1)}$$
 $$  lim_{z\rightarrow 0} \frac{d}{dz}\frac{z }{(e^z - 1)}$$
 $$  lim_{z\rightarrow 0} \frac{(e^z - 1) - (e^z)z}{(e^z - 1)^2}$$

Now just do a couple L'Hopitals and you should get:
Res at z=0:
$$= - \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Thank you! I've just started to study the subject too and your thoughts on the question were very helpful :)

Comment: Glad to be of help! @RodrigoCastañon